# Browser not setting cookie after fetch request javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch

So the first time running this code, the browser set the cookie. But then when I cleared the cookie from the browser and tried to run the code again, the browser isn't setting the cookie any more. I tried multiple browsers and it doesn't work. The fetch request is successful and i can print the cookie value in the console, but the browser wont set the cookie. This is a very annoying problem. I tried using the credential: 'include' also but it didnt work. Getting a CORS error.

I'm pretty new to web development so my knowledge is not very deep.

This is the code on my front end

```
let reqObj = {
        //check email to see if it is a valid format in the login.html user email input
        //name: name.value,
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value
    }


const response = await fetch(api_url + "api/user/login", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(reqObj),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: 'same-origin'

    });

    const jwt = await response.text();
    console.log(jwt)
```

this is the express server code

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    //validate data
    const { error } = loginValidation(req.body)
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    //checking if email is in database
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) return res.status(400).send('Email or password is incorrect')

    //Password is correct
    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
    if (!validPass) return res.status(400).send('Invalid password')

    // Create and assign a token
    const token = jsonWebToken.sign({ _id: user.id }, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);

    //res.header('auth-token', token).send(token);
    res.cookie('auth_token', token, {
        maxAge: 3600,
        httpOnly: true
    }).send(token)

});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in order to use `credentials: 'include'` you have to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header on your response.